# Comparing distributed cloud data storage systems for GeoMesa

Tags: data-storage, geomesa

I am new to GeoMesa and before I choose any data storage on which geomesa can be built on, I want to compare what are the pros and cons for each cloud data storage like

1. Accumulo
2. Kafka
3. BigTable
4. HBase
5. Cassandra

can offer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Great question.  For starters, the GeoMesa Kafka datastore is the odd one out.  It is designed to manage streaming data to provide near real-time processing and viewing of the data.  If that is part of your problem, then Kafka should be part of the solution.

For the remaining four, they are all similar technologies designed to store big data.  GeoMesa started on Accumulo, and has the most features for this database.  If you are looking for some of those GeoMesa features or Accumulo advanced security controls, Accumulo is the way to go.

BigTable is a managed database service provided by Google.  If you are looking to avoid setting up a database, then this option might be best.  Between HBase and Cassandra, most times, people already have a preference.  GeoMesa's support for each is currently evolving.

Comment: Is this answer still current enough?

Comment: Somewhat so.  GeoMesa's HBase support has matured a great deal in the last two years, and that's the biggest change.

Another game changer is running HBase on AWS S3; that can greatly reduce the associate storage costs.  That said, it does require a high degree of dev ops experience, but that's likely too be expected for anything requiring one to run a distributed database;).